# Firefox developer edition. Can't install own extension

Tags: firefox-addon

Writing own extension on xubuntu lts and firefox developer edition. I made a file with a project path in mozilla extension folder. When I run ff-dev, my extension is shown but switched off "because it is not verified" and I can't switch it on. How I can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.
In about:config
xpinstall.signatures.required. change to false